# Reference for nonquasi-split groups of type $E_6$ and $E_7$ over local fields

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, local-fields

The semisimple groups over a local field have been classified by Tits, cf. [1] "Classification of algebraic semisimple groups" in Boulder and [2] "Reductive groups over local fields" in Corvallis.
In both references, Tits gives the construction of the semisimple groups corresponding to each index, except for certain groups of exceptional type.
I am mostly interested in the nonquasi-split groups of exceptional type, that is, using the names in [2, §4] and the indices from [1, Table II]:

- $^3\mathrm{E}_6$ which has index $^1\mathrm{E}_{6,2}^{16}$, and
- $^2\mathrm{E}_7$ which has index $\mathrm{E}_{7,4}^9$

Tits states that these are constructed by means of a central division algebra $D$ of degree $3$ and $2$ respectively, but I cannot find a good reference.
Does anyone know where to look for?

Comment: I suspect that Tits does not give constructions of  $^3\mathrm{E}_6$  and $^2\mathrm{E}_7$ because there is no nice constructions!

Comment: Let $G_0$ be the corresponding simply connected *split* group, and $G_0^{\rm ad}$ be the adjoint group. Let $\eta(D)\in H^2(k,\mu_d)$ denote the class of $D$ (where $\mu_d=Z(G_0)$ and  $d$ is 3 or 2, respectively). Then one should somehow use a construction of Martin Kneser (see also the book by Platonov and Rapinchuk) in order to lift $\eta$ to a cohomology class $\xi\in H^1(k,G_0^{\rm ad})$. Here one should use the assumption that $k$ is a local field.

Comment: Let $c\in Z^1(k,G_0^{\rm ad})$ be a representative of $\xi$. Then it is not hard to twist $G_0$ using $c$, and you obtain the desired group $_c G_0$ of type $^3\mathrm{E}_6$ or $^2\mathrm{E}_7$, respectively, and its faithful $k$-irreducible representation $V$ over $k$ with centralizer $D$ in ${\rm End}_k(V)$.

Answer (score 4):

For $E_7$ there is at least a nice construction at the level of Lie algebra. It is so called Tits (or Tits-Freudenthal) construction that takes a Jordan algebra $J$ and a quaternion algebra $Q$ and produces a Lie algebra of type $E_7$ by some explicit formulas. In your situation you specialize $J$ to the split Albert algebra. The exact reference is

J. Tits, Algebres alternatives, algebres de Jordan et algebres de Lie exceptionnelles. I. Construction, Nederl. Akad. Wetensch. Proc. Ser. A 69 = Indag. Math. 28 (1966), 223–237.

Comment: See [Freudenthal magic square in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_magic_square).